# The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. - SDF file is in the local drive - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

> The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database

I am getting the above error for just two files where the path name is c:\temp\sdf-1\mydatabase.sdf.  The code works fine for almost all sdf databases without issues. I am not using an emulator and I am accessing this file from C# application. I am passing the full path as connectionstring and I am not having issues with other files.  Is there anything I am missing?

```
connectionStr = "c:\\temp\\s1234-1234\mydatabase.sdf"
connectionString = "DataSource="+ connectionStr + _password;
SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine( _connectionString );
en.CreateDatabase();
en.Dispose();
return true();

public bool CreateTransactionLog(string connectionStr)
{
    try
    {
       if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( connectionStr ) )
       {
          //string connectionString = "DataSource=\"C:\\test1.sdf\"; Password=\"mypassword\"";
          _connectionString = "DataSource="+ connectionStr + _password;

          SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine( _connectionString );
          en.CreateDatabase();
          en.Dispose();
          return CreateTransactionTable();

          //return true;
       }

       else
       {
          _connectionString = "DataSource="+ connectionStr + _password;
          return true;
       }           
    }
    catch (SqlCeException e)
    {           
        MessageBox.Show( e.Message ,"Error creating Table",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is strange is that even if the file exists, the application enters into the if Condition to create the database.

Comment: See my reply on the MSDN forum

Answer (score 3):

you missed one `\`

```
connectionStr = "c:\\temp\\s1234-1234\\mydatabase.sdf"
```

Or use

```
connectionStr = @"c:\temp\s1234-1234\mydatabase.sdf"
```

try something like below

```
string sdfPath  = @"c:\temp\s1234-1234\mydatabase.sdf";
var _connectionString  = string.Format("Data Source = {0}; Password = {1}", sdfPath, password);
using (SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(_connectionString))
{
    en.CreateDatabase();
}
return true;
```

Comment: I am indeed using the connectionstr =  "c:\\temp\\s1234-1234\\mydatabase.sdf". My bad, typo on the question I posted. This code has worked for every file expect this file. I can access this file using sql server management studio, so the file is not corrupt or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This Works fine on my PC:

```
        string _password = ";Password=secret";
        string connectionStr = @"c:\temp\s1234-1234\mydatabase.sdf";
        string _connectionString = "Data Source="+ connectionStr + _password;
        using (SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(_connectionString))
        {
            en.CreateDatabase();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. I am not sure what the issue is on my end. Are there other situations where we get this error?

Comment: Wonder if it is related to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/692895/certain-symbols-in-application-path-prevent-sql-server-compact-from-loading